# Environment variable not picking up in dockerfile

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I have a Vue application which I serve with docker, currently I want to use environment variables to target specific project repo. But when I am setting env variables, it's not picking up in dockerfile,

What am I doing wrong in my setup ?

**NPM scripts**.

```
scripts: {
   "build:project1": "vue-cli-service build src/project1/main.js",
   "deploy:project1": "cross-env PROJECT_REPO=project1 bash build_deploy.sh"
}
```

**build_deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

docker build -t ${PROJECT_REPO} .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:${PROJECT_REPO}

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: If this dockerfile was designed to use an environment variable, I would expect to see either an [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) somewhere.

Comment: I have tried using ```--buid-arg``` in build_deploy.sh file but not working with ```RUN npm run build:${PROJECT_REPO}```

Comment: Clarification: I would expect an `ARG` in the dockerfile, not in the command used to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. Found it. I was missing ARG in docker file

```
# build stage
ARG PROJECT_REPO
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

ARG PROJECT_REPO
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:${PROJECT_REPO}

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Reference taken from docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact